# Parameter mapping with Hiera

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to map hiera parameter to another one?

For example, if in hiera there is already a parameter "person::shoe::size" , and puppet module "other_module" needs to lookup parameter like this: hiera(person_shoe_size).

Is it possible to tell hiera that parameter "person_shoe_size" is the same thing as "person::shoe::size", and that hiera(person_shoe_size) should actually be mapped to hiera(person::shoe::size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do a hiera lookup inside of your value.

```
person::shoe::size: "7"
person_shoe_size: "%{hiera('person::shoe::size')}"
```

Looking up either would return `7`. You can also do something like this:

```
hostname: "cool-hostname"
module::fully_qualified_name: "%{hiera('hostname')}.domain.tld"
```

Here, the `fully_qualified_name` parameter will have a value of `cool-hostname.domain-tld`.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I need.

Comment: Wandering how to get array if value is array. Lookup with hiera() as above returns string, and alias() returns nothing for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, you can only return a string this way.

Comment: Yes...realized that hiera() call just returns string. Thanks!